# Flatten a Ruby Array without using built-in 'flatten' method

Tags: ruby

Common way to solve this problem is using `flatten` method.

Can this be done in other ways, say by not using `flatten`?

```
def flatten_array(arr)
  return arr.flatten    
end

print flatten_array([1,2,3,4,[1,2,3,4],5])
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `flatten`?

Comment: Is this an exercise / assignment you're trying to solve?

Comment: It is a exercise,and i have no idea how to solve it without using flatten,so i raise the question here.thx

Comment: If the elements were all integers, as in  your example, you could write: `arr.to_s.tr('[]','').split(',').map(&:to_i)`.

Comment: Here is a non-recursive version (sorry, no indentation as code is in comments - I cant submit answer as question is on hold) - `array = [1,2,3,4,[1,2,[1,2,3,4],4],5]; while array.any? { |e| e.is_a?(Array) }  do array = array.each_with_object([]) do |element, flattened| element.is_a?(Array) ? element.inject(flattened,&:<<) : flattened << element end; end;`

Comment: This question is totally clear. Please vote to reopen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Array
  def flattify
    each_with_object([]) do |element, flattened|
      flattened.push *(element.is_a?(Array) ? element.flattify : element)
    end
  end
end

[1,2,3,4,[1,2,3,4],5].flattify # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

A non-monkey patching `Array` version:

```
def flattify(array)
  array.each_with_object([]) do |element, flattened|
    flattened.push *(element.is_a?(Array) ? flattify(element) : element)
  end
end

flattify([1,2,3,4,[1,2,3,4],5]) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I think i got it,thank you very much

Comment: "flattify" is OK, but I'd prefer "stomp" or "squish".

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I would prefer *flatten*. But *iron* or *implode* sound epic too. xd

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you tell me why it doesn't work if I break that ternary into an `if / else` statement?

  
```ruby
  def flatten_array(array)
    array.each_with_object([]) do |element, flattened|
      if element.kind_of?(Array)
        flattened.push (flatten_array(element)
      else
        flattened.push element
      end
    end 
  end
```

Comment: @jmoon90 could you link to a github gist. It's hard to tell without indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Using recursion to solve this problem.

```
class ArrayConvert
    def self.flatten_array(array,init)
        array.each do |a|
         if a.class==Array
            flatten_array(a,init)
         else
            init << a
         end
        end
      init
    end

  p flatten_array([1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4], 5],[])

end
```

Comment: You can avoid passing empty array as second parameter by defining default value in function definition like this => `def self.flatten_array(array,init=[])`

Comment: It's fine, but unusual to see `p flatten_array...` within the class definition, rather than `ArrayConvert.flatten_array...`.

Comment: Any differences between the two invoke methods? I am confused about this.