# How can I rewrite this flatten method without using class level variables?

Tags: ruby

I am working on building the flatten method in Ruby. Here is my code:

```
require 'byebug'

class Array
  @@new_array = []
  def new_flatten
    self.each do |element|
      if !element.is_a? Array
        @@new_array << element
      elsif element.is_a? Array
        element.new_flatten
      end
    end
    @@new_array
  end
end

test_array = ([1,2,3,[4,5,6,[7]]])
puts test_array.new_flatten == test_array.flatten
```

My question is this. Do I need to use the class level variable? I would like to use an instance variable but it doesn't seem to get called when I do:

```
test_array = []
```

or

```
Array.new([])
```

So I had to create a class-level variable to hold the new flattened array.

Comment: You should use a local variable inside your method.

Comment: So my problem with using a local variable is because of the recursive call... wouldn't a new new_flatten variable get created everytime with its own scope?

Comment: `@@new_array` is a class variable and is the same class variable visible to all the instances of the class. A new instance of a class variable isn't created each time. And the way you've written it, the value of `@@new_array` is only initialized once when the `Array` class is defined. The coding practice of relying on what amounts to a variable that is "global" to the instances and your recursive calls for this problem is not good.

Comment: A related question that asked how to implement flatten: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940239/flatten-a-ruby-array-without-using-built-in-flatten-method/31940781#31940781

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using a class variable is that the same one is visible to all the instances, and `new_flatten` is an operation for an instance. You should refactor your `new_flatten` algorithm so it doesn't rely on what is, in effect, a "global" variable for the method calls.

For example, you can use a local variable and Ruby's facility to append arrays with `+`:

```
class Array
  def new_flatten
    a = []
    self.each do |element|
      if element.is_a? Array
        a += element.new_flatten
      else
        a << element
      end
    end
    a
  end
end
```

Also, as some tweaks of style, when doing an if-else, it's often clearer to state the positive logic first. And, you don't need the `elsif` in this case since the `else` is the complement of the `if`. So rather than:

```
if not something
  do_stuff
elsif opposite_of_not_something
  do_other_stuff
end
```

It's clearer to say:

```
if something
  do_stuff
else
  do_other_stuff
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really confusing. In your title, you talk about calling `initialize`, but there is no `initialize` in your code. In your question, you talk about calling an instance variable, but you can't call variables, only methods.

However, implementing `flatten` is just a simple fold, I don't see the need for storing any intermediate state:

```
class Array
  def new_flatten
    inject([]) {|acc, el| acc + Array(case el when Array then el.new_flatten else el end) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Why use a case statement instead of a ternary operation?

Comment: maybe something like `inject([]){|acc,el| el.is_a?(Array) ? acc.concat(el.new_flatten) : acc << el }`

Comment: I don't like the conditional operator for several reasons. If I were to use a conditional, I would *always* use `if`: `inject([]) {|acc, el| acc + Array(if el.is_a?(Array) then el.new_flatten else el end) }`. I just thought the `case` looked nice. No particular reson.

Comment: Okay I was just wondering because ternary operation has slightly increased performance over both `case` and `if..else`. +1 anyway since the answer is correct and concise.