# Run into this With This recursive funciton

Tags: ruby, recursion

I have problem running this code
its suppose to return a flatten version of this array
please help

```
def flatten(array)
    array.each do |i|
        if i.is_a? Array
            flatten(i)
        else
            @@new_array << i
        end
    end
    return @@new_array
end

flatten([1,2,3,[4,5,[6]]])
```

Comment: Please use code formatting.

Comment: is everyone doing the same homework this morning? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009016/can-you-call-the-initialize-method-of-an-array-in-ruby-by-creating-a-new-array

Comment: Was just wondering the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940239/flatten-a-ruby-array-without-using-built-in-flatten-method/31940781#31940781

Comment: you haven't actually asked a question or mentioned any kind of an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `@@new_array` as a sort of global variable, but you never initialize it. With your current code, in order to for the method to work, you need to reset `@@new_array` each time before calling the method:

```
@@new_array = []
flatten([1,2,3,[4,5,[6]]]) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

However, this implementation is hideous on so many levels (please take no offence). If you were trying to implement the `Array#flatten` method yourself, I would suggest [the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940239/flatten-a-ruby-array-without-using-built-in-flatten-method/31940781#31940781) from a question that asked the same thing a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try array flatten method?

```
[1,2,3,[4,5,[6]]].flatten
```

or you need implements your own methods